# Query specific posts per user selections from dropdown menus

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, database, taxonomy

This may be a little different than most people do. I'm trying to show certain posts that are determined by 4 different "categories." I have a large database table full of "products" (I'm using the WP Products plugin, but I'm willing to change plugins). When a person comes to the site, they'll have 4 drop down menus to chose a specific category in each menu, and then query the results determined by those 4 categories.

I've been looking into `query_posts` or `$wpdb` to implement this. What is the best route to take in this situation?

Comment: Either or really..

Comment: Did you try using WP_Query with [category parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)?

Comment: @BradKaufman - If you are using sub categories, a little more info is needed . for example, what would those 4 menus have ? only 4 categories ? should all 4 have the same categories ? are those 4 menus of 4 different categories that are populated by POSTS ? by Subcategories ? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @krembo99 There's 4 categories with 4 subcategories  for each one. The main categories are empty but the subcategories are loaded with posts. Ideally be able to select a sub category from a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/screenshots/).

If you want to custom-code it, that plugin would be a good place to start and look at how they're doing it...

Comment: Hi WPMU-DEV, Welcome to WPSE.  Signatures or tag-lines are not allowed in answers or questions.  Please see the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)